# How to check if my gamepad works well?

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to calibrate my gamepads? I have 2 Genesis gamepads and use it while playing fifa 16. I think that one of the buttons doesnt work sometimes. Is there any way on windows 10 to check if everything is all right with my gamepads?

Comment: I am not aware of any software that exists that would allow you to calibrate the device.  If one of the buttons does not work "somtimes", calibrating, wouldn't work magic.  Sounds like you should replace the gamepad

Comment: the think is I am not sure if it doesnt work... I need to confirm that... Is it possible?

Comment: Select a game which supports a gamepad.  Map an action which you can easily test (jump, single fire, ect ) to the problem button.  If you press it, and the action does not happen always, then you should replace the gamepad.